# Conflict between horizontal scroll bar and footer in IE browser(version:11.17)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]
    Q) Scroll bar is coming  on top of footer (i'm using twitter bootstrap )
       I tried to change the Padding-bottom as 10PX its working in IE but its 
       not looking Good in Chrome please give me a solution thanks!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.6">
<title>United</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11">
        <a href="~/">
            <img class="logo" alt="United Logo"
                 src="~/Content/images/UnitedLogo.png">
            <h3 class="caption">EUSSO Tools</h3>
        </a>
   </div></div>

  @Html.Action("UserMenu", "Home")

<div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
       </div>
    <div class= "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-
    bottom"role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text">
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - United Ltd.All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>



        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[Click here to find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukhuB.jpg)

Comment: you are not providing any code.

Comment: I am new to this site correct me if i did anything wrong thanks

Comment: edit your question and add the HTML code in there. Check out Markdown formatting guidlines to make it look nice. also let others know which version of IE you are using. Generally the format of an SO question should be :
i am doing [THIS]; i expected [THAT]; i am getting [THIS INSTEAD];

Comment: @ramrunner: I have only one issue scrollbar is coming top of footer (only in Internet explorer) except that everything working fine in other browers

Comment: You need to provide a complete but minimal amount of markup that we can use to reproduce the problem. What you show does not do that. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob:Check it now i added full code thanks in advance